# complexity between log(n) and log(log(n))

Tags: algorithm

I want to know about the complexity classes between log(n) and log(log(n))? my simulation results are loosely bound with 0(log(n) and also it is also not fit with 0(log(log(n))). so tell me some middle complexity classes between them.

Comment: Complexity is not measured by simulation :-)

Comment: @Bergi: That is true, but given the correct $n$ you may be able to show the bounds in a plot.

Comment: sir.. i ploted it. but it is not bounded with log(log(n)). it is bounded with log(n). but very loosely.. so i want to know midde classes of complexcity to bound the plot

Comment: You should mathematically analyse your algorithm to determine the complexity - I believe there are infinitely many complexity classes between any two given complexity classes (which is hopelessly too broad for a [so] question).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Actually `O(log(sqrt(n))) = O(1/2.log(n)) = O(log(n))`.

Comment: @Dukeling Aah missed that! sorry :)

Comment: How about `O((log(log(n))^k)` for any `k > 1`? But the people above are right, you should analyse running times formally. Experiments, while sometimes useful indicators, don't give you a foolproof guarantee.

Comment: @G.Bach THANKU.. IT MAY WORK.. I WILL TRY IT.. :)

Comment: If you want to prove that `O(log log n) ⊊ O(log^k log n) ⊊ O(log n)` for any `k > 1`, you may want to substitute `x` for `log n` and use that `lim n->infinity (n^i)/(log n) = infinity` for all `i > 0`.

Comment: However, `O(sqrt(log(n))` is a subset of `O(log(n))`, and not a subset of `O(log(log(n))`

Comment: @amit Yeah, that's basically the same idea approached from the other direction :)

Answer (score 1):

There are infinite number of classes that are "between" `O(logn)` and `O(loglogn)`, for example - look at the family of functions: `{ f_k(n) = (log(n))^k | k < 1 }` (Note that this family of function alone is infinite).

For each `f_k` as defined above, it is easy to see that `f_k` is in `O(logn)` but is NOT in `O(loglogn)`, and is actually defining a new class of functions `O(f_k)`, which is an inequal subset of `O(logn)`, but is not a subset of `O(loglogn)`.

One example for such a function `f_k` is `f_1/2 = sqrt(log(n))`.

---

Proving the above claims is easy with introducing a new variable `x=log(n)`, and then you get:

```
f_k(n) = (log(n))^k = x^k
```

and it is an already solved problem that

```
O(loglogn) = O(log(x)) < O(x^k) < O(x) = O(logn)
```